# Resize QPixmap without scaling the image

Tags: python, pyside6

I am trying to scale a paint overlay and a image background. The user should be able to paint on the background, but into a second QPixmap. This is working with the following code:

```py
class Annotator(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.gt_pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
        self.gt_pixmap.fill(Qt.white)
        self.original_pixmap = self.gt_pixmap.copy()
        self.annotation_pixmap = QPixmap(size)
        self.annotation_pixmap.fill(Qt.transparent)
```

Now I want to add the option to zoom in the image and the annotation.
The following code works, but changes the annotation and most importantly changes the resolution of the annotation which leads to strange behavior while annotation.

The latter could be addressed by scaling the QPen according to the image, but the problem with changed annotations remains. Ideally I would like the the image to be scaled without the resolution to be changed.

Here the code used for scaling:

```py
    def scale_image(self, factor):
        self._scale_factor *= factor
        new_size = self._scale_factor * self.original_pixmap.size()
        self.annotation_pixmap = self.annotation_pixmap.scaled(new_size, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.gt_pixmap = self.original_pixmap.scaled(new_size, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.setFixedSize(new_size)
```